# Jquery script not running in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new to the jquery scripts, but I have an HTML table structured as follows inside my php code:

```
print <<<End_Of_HTML

<table class="misc_items timecard_list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th align="left" class="job_code">In/Out</th>
    <th align="center">Time</th>
    <th align="center">Date</th>
    <th align="center" class="hrs" title="Regular work hours.">Hrs</th>$overtime_col$total_col
    <th align="left" class="notes">Notes</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
End_Of_HTML;
```

I then have a PHP-MySQL query populate that table with results and wanted to total up the hrs class based on the job_code classes value. I have this jquery script, which works on JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Lj6he/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var temp = [];
$('.job_code').each(function(index, element){
    var text = $(this).text();
    temp.push(text);
});

// remove duplicates
var job_code = [];
$.each(temp, function(index, element){
    if($.inArray(element, job_code) === -1) job_code.push(element);
});

var sum = {};
$.each(job_code, function(index, element){
    var total = 0;
    $('.job_code:contains('+element+')').each(function(key, value){
        total += parseInt($(this).next('td.hrs').text());
        sum[index] = {'job_code' : element, 'total': total};
    });
});

console.log(sum);

$.each(sum, function(index, element){
    $('#total').append('<p>Total for '+element.job_code+': '+element.total+'</p>');
});

});
```

But when I enter it into my PHP file as follows it doesn't display what is seen on JSFiddle....any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
$PAGE_SCRIPT = <<<End_Of_HTML
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.totals.js"></script>
End_Of_HTML;
```

It just seems to not be displaying the results of the jquery on the page. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Are you importing the jquery library? I only see an import for your script

Comment: Yes Ryan is right, import jquery library file first

Comment: Can one of you show me where I would do that in my code. Sorry. No idea with jquery stuff.

Comment: @h3tr1ck - research the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Drop this line into the head section of your html output.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

that will import jQuery for you

ps, be sure to include it before any dependencies

Comment: Ok. I did that, but it is still not displaying the script results underneath the table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending your output to a non-existent element with id `#total`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the jquery library is referenced prior to your javascript code import.

The sample PHP code is missing

```
<div id="total">
</div>
```

This is the Div where the content is added.